# wordpress wp_nav_menu : how to wrap each element of the menu with an id corresponding to the element title?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

i'd like to display an image depending on which element of the menu is cliked or mouse-over.

Having a different id for each element of the menu would be handy in order to handle li elements with JQuery.

how could i wrap each element of the menu with an id corresponding to its title ?
Any alternatives to make this working?

so far my function call is as such :

```
if ( function_exists('has_nav_menu') && has_nav_menu('red sea') )
  {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
       'depth' => 4,
      'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
       'container' => 'ul', 
       'menu_id' => 'nav', 
        'menu_class' => 'fr',
        'theme_location' => 'pages mer rouge',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>' ) );
    }
```

i don't know what that %1$s or %2$s means ?

Comment: %1$s will be replaced by the id in wp_nav_menu, so do %2$s with class and %3$s with the li elements.

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress is already adding id's to your menu. Just take a look to the code of your website in the browser... it looks something like that:

```
<li id="menu-item-17" ...>Title1</li>
<li id="menu-item-18" ...>Title2</li>
<li id="menu-item-19" ...>Title3</li>
<li id="menu-item-20" ...>Title4</li>
```

You can use these IDs to add different behaviour for each list-item ;)

Comment: sure ..i would like to have a more obivous name for a better maintainability...i would like to replace menu-item-17 by the name i gave to this element in the back office

Answer (score 1):

Each Wordpress page has a unique id. Right-click and inspect the element on your site to see it's id or, alternatively, go to your wordpress pages, and you should find the page-item-id there. This is assigned as the id for each list item in the wp-nav-menu. It's pretty much the only good way to style each item. Alternatively you could dabble in using [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) if your menu is not going to change... Hope it helps.